# R: Counting Text Mismatches Within Column Name Across a Series of Columns

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have a set of columns that have names comprised of multiple items, similar to those in:

```
df1<-data.frame(`apple,onion,pear`=0,`apple,banana,onion,pear`=0,`banana,pear`=0)
```

I also have a set of columns in a data frame that contain items:

```
df2<-data.frame(thing_1=c('apple','onion','pear','banana'),thing_2=c('onion',NA,'banana','tree'),thing_3=c(NA,NA,'apple','pear'),thing_4=c(NA,NA,NA,'lobster'))
```

For each of the itemlist-named columns, I would like to have a count of the items in each row of `df2` that are not present within the column name.  NAs should not count as mismatches.  Hundreds of rows and columns exist within the true data set, but a low, fixed number of `thing_` columns exists.

Desired output would be as follows:

```
desiredresult<-data.frame(thing_1=c('apple','onion','pear','banana'),thing_2=c('onion',NA,'banana','tree'),thing_3=c(NA,NA,'apple','pear'),thing_4=c(NA,NA,NA,'lobster'),
                      'apple,onion,pear'=c(0,0,1,3),`apple,banana,onion,pear`=c(0,0,0,2),'banana,pear'=c(2,1,1,2))
```

[image]

As a brief explanation of the logic:

For the `apple.onion.pear` column, row 1 is 0 because "apple" in `thing_1` and "onion" in `thing_2` both appear in the column name, and NAs cause no mismatch.  Row 3 has a value of 1 because `thing_2` is "banana", which does not appear in the column name, and all other items are either NA or can be found in the column name.

So far, I have been working with `grepl()`, but I'm stumped!  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

strsplit(names(df1), split="\\.") %>%
  map2_dfc(syms(names(df1)),
           ~ transmute(df2, !!(.y) := apply(df2, 1, function(z) sum(!z %in% .x & !is.na(z))))) %>%
  bind_cols(df2, .)
```

**Output:**

```
  thing_1 thing_2 thing_3 thing_4 apple.onion.pear apple.banana.onion.pear
1   apple   onion    <NA>    <NA>                0                       0
2   onion    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>                0                       0
3    pear  banana   apple    <NA>                1                       0
4  banana    tree    pear lobster                3                       2
  banana.pear
1           2
2           1
3           1
4           2
```